# Advanced Flex custom components for working with graphics and text

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm looking for a new, modern components with enhanced functionality for working with graphics and text.

For example by mouse over to the text appears a icon click on that appears a panel into which you can change the font, font size, font color, letter-range, etc.

With graphics by pointing resizing handles appear, rotation, reflection, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what functionality you want.  Can you clarify or expand on specifics?

Comment: For example there is RichTextEditor, but need a more flexible, customizable component.
For graphics i need something with which it is easy and convenient to resize, rotate and do different transformations of the form.
The above features can be added to any text and graphic objects of the project.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a custom tooltip, that has the options to change/edit the appearance of the UIComponent that was hovered over. This is a tricky mofo of a component to make. I made a custom tooltip based on a Canvas, that has an item renderer associated with it. If your in earnest, I could probably put together a usable example and post it (on my blog or something).

If you hover over a component, a regular toolip appears, but when you hover over the tooltip, it expands out to a custom tooltip. I used Timer objects with event listeners added.

After that, you'll need to do all the transform stuff. Probably out of the scope of a single StackOverflow question to be honest.

Comment: Oh, no. I'm probably wrong to put it. I need components like this http://www.greensock.com/transformmanageras3/ but free. This is for graphics, but there are similar components for advanced text edition.